# Findbugs Java Ignore Fields or Lines

Tags: java, annotations, findbugs

Is it possible to make a Findbugs deactivation annotation for a specific field or line instead of deactivation of the whole check of all method contained fields?

```
@edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressFBWarnings(value="BEAN_SUPER_CALL_ON_OBJECT",
justification = "I don't want to overwrite the method, but otherwise our equals check issues a warning")
@Override
public boolean equals(final Object obj) {

    // this should not be ignored
    super.test(obj);

    // this should be ignored
    return super.equals(obj);

}
```

This won't work:

```
@edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressFBWarnings(value="BEAN_SUPER_CALL_ON_OBJECT")
return super.equals(obj);
```

Also this won't work:

```
@edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressFBWarnings(value="BEAN_SUPER_CALL_ON_OBJECT")
super.equals(obj);
```

This works, but the warning still pops up:

```
@edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressFBWarnings(value="BEAN_SUPER_CALL_ON_OBJECT")
boolean ret_val = super.equals(obj);
return ret_val;
```

Comment: Um, *why* are you overriding that method that way?

Comment: It's just a simplified example, most common screens won't be able to get the code of this method on screen xD This one makes no sense, but the problem is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible for fields, but not for single lines of code. According to the [FindBugs 3.0 documentation](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/annotations.html), the `@SuppressFBWarnings` annotation can be applied to

> **[Target]** Type, Field, Method, Parameter, Constructor, Package

<sub>(In the `edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations` package, `@SuppressFBWarnings` and `@SuppressWarnings` are equivalent.)</sub>

As you can see, `LOCAL_VARIABLE` and `ANNOTATION_TYPE` are not in the list. Although there is no `@Target` element on the annotation, FindBugs ignores it in these two cases.